# Outlook: multiple calendars and meeting requests

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, meeting-request

**I've edited my post. The first one was unclear and contained mistakes.**

I've two calendars in Outlook. The first one is an Exchange account, the second a PST-file (outlook.pst).

I use Exchange for appointments only. E-Mail is sent by POP3 / SMTP only.

Now, accepted meeting requests should be added to the Exchange calendar. They were received by POP3. I could select the Exchange data-file as default location, but on the other hand, e-mails should be sent by SMTP so the outlook.pst has to be default (otherwise the exchange account is used).

Is it possible to add pop3 invitations to the Exchange calendar without making the Exchange Account the default data file?

Thank you in advance.

Chris

Answer (score 1):

No, it will always default to your Exchange calendar, you will have to copy or move it to your PST Calendar, as PSTs in general are meant for archiving.

**Update for comment**

I thought you were referring to an archive pst file, not an imap-mapped pst file. I don't think you can do imap calendaring. What version of Outlook is this, and where *exactly* is this calendar in your folder structure? Please double check b/c I'm pretty sure that imap-mapped accounts can't do calendaring, @ least in Outlook 2010.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. Outgoing mails should be sent by SMTP (from IMAP account). That's why the PST-file is the default data-storage. Meetings should be added to the Exchange Account. Now, meetings are added to the PST file. Is there any way to change this?

Comment: Sorry, my fault! It is Outlook 2010 and a POP account, that uses the outlook.pst. This is one calendar, the other is Exchange.

Comment: outlook.pst, yeah that sounds like an archive calendar. Here's how to change your default http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-outlook/how-to-set-default-calendar-for-populating/6c613320-4ecb-477f-be62-894a5786ad6b

Comment: MDMoore313, thanks again. I've updated my opening question. I've added why I can't change my default personal folder file, so I guess there's no way to use the meeting requests like we woud like.